# AutoMapper : Map a destination property to a different source property/type based on some logic

Tags: .net, automapper, idatareader

I want to map a Source object to Destination object which has some extra properties which are not directly equivalent to the source properties. Consider below example:

```
class Source { string ImageFilePath; }

class Destination { bool IsFileSelected; bool IsFileGif; }
```

Mapping Logic for IsFileGif:

```
destinationObj.IsFileGif = Path.GetExtension(sourceObj.ImageFilePath) == ".gif" ? true : false;
```

Mapping Logic for IsFileSelected:

```
destinationObj.IsFileSelected = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceObj.ImageFilePath) ? false : true;
```

Also, since my source is an IDataReader, I would wish to know how to map the field/column of an IDataReader object to my Destination property.

Can we achieve this using an inline code or do we have to use Value Resolvers for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the MapFrom method?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source , Destination>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFileGif, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Path.GetExtension(sourceObj.ImageFilePath) == ".gif")
 .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFileSelected, opt =>  opt.MapFrom(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceObj.ImageFilePath));
```

Regarding the IDataReader, I think you should be mapping between your classes (Source to Destination), not from an IDataReader to Destination...

Comment: Thanks @Igomide, the MapFrom method worked. The Source class was simply used for the sake of simplicity. In my real scenario, the source is actually an IDataReader created from a DataTable object retrieved from the database. And I have written a generic extension method that will do the IDataReader -> IEnumerable<T> mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out mapping from an IDataReader to a Destination object:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Destination>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.IsFileSelected,
                         o => o.MapFrom(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.GetValue(s.GetOrdinal("ImageFilePath")).ToString())))
                    .ForMember(d => d.IsFileGif,
                         o => o.MapFrom(s => Path.GetExtension(s.GetValue(s.GetOrdinal("ImageFilePath")).ToString()) == ".gif"));
```

Would appreciate if anyone verify's this code or suggest if a better alternative exists.